# Use only parts of a string

Tags: jquery, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
let conSelected = "f0_leg0_c2";
```

I want to use only the first part of it to find all divs starting with (in this sample) `f0_leg0`

How can this be achieved without concatenating `conSelected.split[0] + conSelected.split[1]` or something similar? Is there an easier way?

Comment: If the structure of the string follows a pattern you could use a RegExp, otherwise splitting and concatenating the first two parts is easy enough.

Comment: ok, I had hoped there would be another and maybe faster way

Comment: RegExp would be the fastest, although with such a simple use case any speed difference would not be noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to concatenate string in the way you have in your example you can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the last index of "_" and sub-string the string..

`var str = conSelected.substring(0, conSelected.lastIndexOf("_"))`

```js
let conSelected = "f0_leg0_c2";

console.log(conSelected.substring(0, conSelected.lastIndexOf("_")));
```

Comment: Excactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi if this answer solves your problem, then you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can split by "_", splice and then join:

```
"f0_leg0_c2".split("_").splice(0, 2).join("_")
```